# Derivative of $\pmb{A}^T\pmb{x}$ with respect to $\pmb{A}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, matrix-calculus

Let $\pmb{A}$ be a real matrix and $\pmb{x}$ a vector such that $\pmb{A}^T\pmb{x}$ exists. Then how do I calculate the following result?
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{A} } \pmb{A}^T\pmb{x} = ?$$
Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to find any information on this.

Comment: You can look for it in here www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf

Comment: @DaveNguyen I have only found $\frac{\partial \pmb{a}^T\pmb{A}^T\pmb{b}}{\partial \pmb{A}} = \pmb{b}\pmb{a}^T$, and hence, I'm still at a loss.

Comment: @DaveNguyen that would be applying a vector result to matrices.  The fact that one can do this (if this actually works) is at the very least non-trivial

Comment: Hope you're already aware of it, but if not you're deriving a vector with respect to a matrix so you have a 3-dimensional tensor there which will be just $x$ but repeated lots of times and spread around these 3 dimensions. That said I know nothing about tensor notation

Comment: Do you want $\frac{\partial}{\partial A}$ as linear map or as tensor?

Comment: @user251257 It is an eventuality that the calculation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \pmb{A} } \pmb{A}^T\pmb{x}$ is a tensor. So I suppose that's the construction I require.

Comment: just compute the partial derivative and order them in the way you like. there are unfortunately many conventions

Comment: The function $f(A) = A^T x$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb R^{m \times n}$ to $\mathbb R^n$.  So the derivative $Df(A)$ is just the same linear transformation.  In other words, $Df(A) = f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is a matrix form acceptable as an answer?

As I said in my comment, I know nothing about tensor notation. What I usually do to avoid it is [vectorizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) something. Here what you can do to stay in the linear algebra world is take the derivative with respect to a vectorized version of your matrix:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \operatorname{vec} (A) } A^T x$$

Often when you do this kind of thing, [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) will be your friend. It happens for a $n \times m$ matrix $A$ that $$A^Tx = (I_m \otimes x)^T \operatorname{vec} (A)$$

Sorry, no proof, check it with Matlab or Octave with the `kron` function.

Now that you have this the derivative reduces to $$\frac{\partial}{\partial a } X a$$ where $a$ is $\operatorname{vec} (A)$ and $X=(I_m \otimes x)^T$. And this is actually equal to $X$ (or its transpose, I don't know the convention).

Long story short:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \operatorname{vec} (A) } A^T x = (I_m \otimes x)^T$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{f(A)}=A^T\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector-valued function, then it will have $n$ components. Each component has the formula:

$$f_i(A)=\langle \mathbf{a}_i,\mathbf{x}\rangle$$

Where $\mathbf{a}_i$ is the $i$th column vector of $A$. The derivative of $f_i(A)$ wrt $A$ is the matrix given by:

$$\frac{d}{dA}f_i(A)=\left(\frac{df_i}{da_{ij}}\right)_{i,j \in 1...n}$$

Therefore, you will be calculating a series of $n$ matrices. Note that the linearity of $f_i$ means that only one column will contain non-zero entries.

Answer (score 1):

Define the function $F(A,x)=A^{\perp}x$. This is a function of $A\in M^{n\times n}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Specifically,
$$
                      F : M^{n\times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}.
$$
To take the derivative of $F$ with respect to $A$, you allow $A$ to vary by adding a (small) $h \in M^{n\times n}$ and find a linear function $L : M^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that
$$
                 F(A+h,x)-F(A,x) = Lh+o(h),
$$
where $L$ depends on $A$, $x$ and $o$ means $o(h)/|h|\rightarrow 0$ as $|h|\rightarrow 0$. In this case,
$$
                 F(A+h,x)-F(A,x)=h^{\perp} x+0.
$$
The linear function $L$ is $Lh = h^{\perp}x$. It looks wrong because we're used to writing everything in terms of a matrix for a linear function. You can do that by choosing a basis of $M^{n\times n}$, or you can recognize that the following defines a linear function of $h$ for fixed $A$, $x$.
$$
                      L(A,x)h = h^{\perp} x
$$
So the linearization of $F$--which is the derivative--is the linear function
$$
                    L(A,x) : M^{n\times n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}
$$
defined by $L(A,x)h = h^{\perp}x$. The derivative is independent of $A$, but does depend on $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(A)=A^Tx$. Then it is easy to see
$$ \lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(A+tH)-f(A)}{t}=H^Tx$$
and hence
$$ Df(A)H=H^Tx.$$